# DTD when the element has more than 1 attributes

Tags: xml, dtd

For this xml line

```
<Employment type ="Full">...</Employment>
```

I have wrote this dtd line

```
<!ATTLIST Employment type (Full|Part) "Full">
```

Now, what if I have more than one attributes like this

```
<Institution from ="2011" to ="2014">...</Institution>
```

How do I represent its dtd?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another `<!ATTLIST>` for the second attribute.

So it might be something like

```
<!ATTLIST Institution from CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST Institution to CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: W3Schools is not held in high regards by some parts of the development community.

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple attributes in a single `ATTLIST` for an element...

```
<!ATTLIST Institution
          to   CDATA #REQUIRED
          from CDATA #REQUIRED>
```